# Python Geocoder's Google Provider returns None

Tags: python-3.x, github, google-api, geocoding

Geocoder's Google Provider returns "None"
This is a Python library for Geocoding.
[This is Geocoder](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder)

```
>>> import geocoder
>>> g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA')
>>> g.latlng
None
```

Please help me get the results instead of None.